# What is the remainder when $32^{32}$ is divided by 3

Tags: soft-question, modular-arithmetic, binomial-theorem

What is the remainder when $32^{32}$ is divided by 3 ?

**MY ATTEMPT**

$$32^{32}=(2)^{160}$$

$$32^{32}=(3-1)^{160}$$

$$32^{32}=3M+(-1)^{160}$$

According to binomial expansion $$32^{32}=3M+1$$

Thus the remainder is 1.

Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: Such questions have been answered here already often, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712128/finding-remainder-when-323232-is-divided-by-7?rq=1). Bill's answer solves your question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works.  Similarly

$$32^{32}=(33-1)^{32}=33M+(-1)^{32}=3\times 11M+1$$

so the remainder is $1$